# Is or are - "The most preferable length of the internship is 3 months but 2 is also acceptable"

Tags: grammatical-number, sentence

Could you tell me, what is the correct form?

> "The most preferable length of the internship is/ are 3 months but 2 is/are
>   also acceptable"

My intuition tells me that should be 'is' but 'are' seems to be more proper for number 3.

Comment: Nicole's answer is true, but you should note that your `is/are`s relate to `length` and there is no cause for confusion.

Comment: No, you don't say _the most preferable_. You say _the preferred_; it's not the addressee's preference you're discussing, it's **your** preference. Get that straight right away. As for _is/was_, the subject is _length_, which is singular. English auxiliary verbs like _be_ agree with their subjects; "3 months" is the predicate noun phrase, not the subject. The auxiliary _be_ is required for predicate nouns: _That man is an impostor; his shoe size is 7, not 9_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When numbers are used to talk about time, cost, or distance they are singular because the whole thing is taken as one concept:

- The preferable length of the internship **is** three months.
- Three hours **feels** like forever when you're just sitting there.
- Fifty dollars **is** a lot for one book.
- Three miles **is** a long way to go on foot.

Answer (score 0):

"The most preferable length of the internship is three months, but two is also acceptable"

Generally, we should spell the numbers from 0-9.
And I think a comma should come before the conjunction "but."