# "5 votes {was/were} chosen to be the number of close votes needed...": Which is correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

"5 votes **was** chosen to be the number of close votes needed to close a question on Stack Exchange."

Grammarly says that I should change "was" to "were," but it doesn't sound right to me. What's the correct conjugation to use here, singular or plural?

Comment: Similar (but not identical): [“1 or 2 friends is enough” or “1 or 2 friends are enough”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385704), [Is or are - “The most preferable length of the internship is 3 months but 2 is also acceptable”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245880)

Comment: You should always be suspicious of what *Grammarly* tells you. It makes a lot of mistakes, and in this case, it's wrong.

Comment: The elephant in the room is that the first "votes" has no right to be there in the first place. What do you mean, "votes were chosen to be the number of votes"? No. Five was chosen to be the number. Not five votes. Just five. Five is a number. Votes is not. And yes, uninstall Grammarly. Right now. It is broken, it is wrong, it makes horrible mistakes even in its adverts. Every second that you have it installed will make you dumber until you reach the level of stupidity exhibited by its creators. You know English. Grammarly doesn't, and couldn't even if it tried, and it doesn't even try.

Comment: @RegDwigнt An excellent point, and one that I'd overlooked in my answer.

Comment: You using quotes. Why?

Comment: @RegDwigнt: That’s not an elephant; that’s a gray sheepdog. OK, the example sentence could be phrased better — that happens often with example sentences ([here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/450697/26083#comment1084724_450697 "What is the correct way to use the genitive in “Marge’s and Homer’s personalities are the opposite”?") is a recent instance). Big deal. It doesn’t negate the validity of the question; just consider examples like “Five pounds is the most I can carry” and “Seven days make a week.”  I suspect that this issue has been handled before, but I can’t find a good dup target.

Comment: Related: [Plural/singular verb agreement with units](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/41155/26083).  Loosely related: [Arithmetic expressions: singular or plural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/162222/357)

Comment: A _total_ of 5 votes _was_ required to close a question on Stack Exchange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To paraphrase your sentence, you would say:

> **The number** of close votes needed **was five**.

The subject of the sentence is *the number* (singular) so the verb takes a singular form.

(Or, more precisely, it's the entire subject phrase *the number of close votes needed*, because *the number* is modified by *of close votes needed*. But for the sake of this explanation, it's easiest to think of just *the number*.)

Just as you would say:

> The number **is** five.
>   The numbers **were** five and six.

Again, the verb matches the singular or plural subjects.

So, going back to the actual phrasing of your sentence:

> 5 **was** chosen to be **the number** of close votes needed.

The subject remains *the number* and the verb remains in the singular.

**Note**: As per a perfectly correct comment, the number of votes cannot be *5 votes*; it is simply *5*. I have edited the actual sentence to correct this.

The sentence in question has been constructed in such a way that *5 votes* misleads you into thinking that it's the subject.

Comment: In the sentence *Four votes is not enough to close a question*, is the subject *enough*? How does that work, when  you would never say *Enough to close a question is not four votes*.

Comment: The essentials of this sentence: **Four votes are** not enough. (This is similar to the James Bond movie ***The World Is*** *Not Enough*.)